# Is this function convex and differentiable?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$$(|y|-x)_{+}^2$$
Is this function with square of positive part of
$$|y|-x$$
convex? Also, is it differentiable? If yes, then is it twice differentiable?

I tried plotting epigraph of the function and from the epigraph I think it is convex, but I am not sure about it. Also, I believe this is differentiable for
$$|y|-x\geq0\text.$$

Comment: Are you considering it as a function of both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I assume the function is $f(x,y)=[|y|-x]_+^2$? This is a compact description of the function, so just try breaking it down to cases. Think what happens $|y|-x<0$? And when $|y|-x \geq 0$? Also, consider $y>0,\; y<0$. Looking at the "boundary points" between these domains of the function will give you the answer on convexity and differentiability.